# Backward transformation of georeferenced image: from GeoTIFF to TIFF

Tags: raster, pixel, array, rotate, affine

What's the processing procedure to realize a backward transformation, from a GeoTIFF image to its native array of pixels?
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: A GeoTIFF is a TIFF, with extra information encoded. It is not necessary to convert it to extract pixel data with a TIFF reader.

Comment: Hi Vince. I need to create a matrix with all image pixel values (DN) except for the black pixels (=0) which were added during the geo-referring process (i.e.: the affine transformation). In other words, I have to produce the native sensor array of DNs starting from the geo-referred image.

Comment: Ahh. That might not be reversible. Far better to use the original file (pre-georeferencing).